# Get attachments if title contain mention word? - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, attachment

I want to get all attachments if their title contain mention word(keyword) in code. i do research on this and able to do this with help of this plugin "Custom Content Shortcode", its do good job, but i need some more details and some extra part fecth by this plugin code that i dont want i end up with this. Now i think if this plugin can do this hope their is any php code can also do this. So I need help here. If some one help to done this with php code.

Shortcodes I used  with this plugin to get result

```
[loop type=attachment ] 
[if field=title contains=my keyword empty=false]
[field title-link]
[/if]
[/loop]
```

Problem with above code is they search for all files and show blank spaces for that titles that dont have "my keyword" and also show titles for that have "my keyword" like bellow

```
my keyword use in seo of title 
<blank line>
<blank line>
<blank line>
why i used my keyword
<blank line>
my keyword benefits 
<blank line>
<blank line>
<blank line>
<blank line>
<blank line>
<blank line>
<blank line>
<blank line>
```

> Blank line means nothing show just empty space

So thats wy I need php code so i can get only titles and other fields (image, parent post link etc ) not these blank likes with the result.
Hope you understand what I want.

Update : in short Im looking for help for code that can find if media(attachment/attachment's) title contain mention keyword in php code then get ( title of that image, parent post link, image url to display image etc )

Answer (score 1):

this might helpful to you.

```
$query_images_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
while ($query_images->have_posts()) : $query_images->the_post();
    $link  = get_the_permalink($post->ID);
    //the_permalink();
    if(preg_match('/yourkeyword/',$link)){
        echo $link;
    }
    echo '<br/>';
    endwhile;
die;
```

If you want media title that contain the specific word than you have to use get_the_title() instead of get_the_permalink();

Comment: @kirshna thakor  thanks for your time and help. but when I put this code in my theme file it show nothing just blank page, i dont know what is the problem but i have keyword in my image title that i mention in your given code, but its show nothing. please help me.

Comment: you have to replace get_the_permalink() with get_the_title() and also replace your keyword in this function preg_match('/yourkeyword/',$link)

Comment: Here I filter data by there link so if you want filter it by title then replace get_the_title().By the way what is you keyword ? tell me I can help you with that.

Comment: yes, i do this already, but got nothing  $link  = get_the_title($post->ID);
    //the_permalink();
    if(preg_match('/My keyword/',$link)){
        echo $link;
    }

Comment: what is your keyword?

Comment: these are students names ( like tom, neha, preet etc )

Comment: this name is included in image title? r you sure? in media section ?

Comment: Yes, i use name in image title and even in image alt.. like our student neha .. preet is our best student etc

Comment: give me one full image title for example

Comment: for : we wish our student happy birthday, so make image and upload with title = Happy birthday Neha.   Happy Birthday Preet. this is one of the titles we used in birthday section .

Comment: preg_match('/Happy\s*Birthday\s*Neha') use this. Here \s* map any number of space. please put \s* instead of \s in my edit.

Comment: and yes change  'post_status'    => 'inherit', to 'post_status' => 'publish'

Comment: one thing more is it case sensitive - i mean if we use keyword "/neha/" and some title like Neha happy birthday and some like NEHA happy birthday is it ok or not ?